# What am I doing wrong? I added a left nav but instead of left within the website it is left below it

Tags: css

```
#container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000000;
}
#header {
    width: 884px;
    height: 113px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url(mybanner.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
}
#leftnav{
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #F8AA3C;
    border-right: 1px dashed #694717;
}
#body{
    width: 550px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

Comment: @Kevin Boucher, you've changed the CSS declarations when you improved the formatting, Randall originally had `#` before each declaration, `#container`, `#header`, `#leftnav` and `#body`.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro No, I don't think so, I just did an undo back to the original state. I see no hashmarks.

Comment: @Kevin Boucher check the original code on the **Rev** combo box if you edit it again. Without them only the `body` CSS declaration would apply. Even as it is, Randall, if you want some help you have to paste the HTML and CSS code.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro Where is that Rev combo box? (I clicked into EDIT mode again, but didn't see it.)

Comment: @Kevin Boucher check this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/aXs39dl.png) I took.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro Wow! I do not see that Rev field. The Title textbox is the top form element for me in edit mode. WTH? Oh yeah -- remind me never to format somebody's code in jsFiddle again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Missing information such as what is your DOM structure and what the element that trying to put left to some container, I saw you used `float:left` style so my guess it is some block element, in that case I can only suggest adding `position: relative` style to your `leftnav` element.

Comment: Why guess when the question clearly doesn't provide enough information?

Comment: Hi Pavel, Yes I do have position: relative. My left nav was outside the body rather than within. Thanks!